# How is data written to memory

Tags: memory, store

When we store data in memory. 
How does it get stored, so it can recognize what type of data it is when loaded.
What I want to ask is how the data types like Natural numbers, integers, characters, etc are stored in memory. So they can be recognized easily later when extracted from memory.

When we see at memory, what we see are hex numbers.
How can we relate these hex numbers for ASCII value or Integer Value or any other etc.

Comment: It does not differ. You will have to know what to read and how to interpret the data.

Comment: sounds like a homework question to me? do some research and then when/if you get stuck we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Since all of your data is written in binary, there isn't much difference between how the char `a` is written and how the int `97` is written, since they represent the same binary string (at least the last 8 bits of those strings). That being said, when you read from memory, you read a data type, by that type, you know how you should interpret the data

Answer (score 0):

Memory does not operate in terms of "character" or "integer", these are high-level concepts that assume an abstract machine.

Typically, but not necessarily, a character is just an integer with a smaller size, often 8 bits (but a character could as well be 32 bits!) which represents one symbol or letter, rather than a discrete number. In some cases, a character may even be encoded using a variable length.

Memory operates in terms of bits that are organized in bytes (smallest directly addressable unit) or words. These are -- unbeknownst to you -- organized in banks. The hardware typically allows access in units called "cache lines", but this is something that happens secretly behind your back.
In assembler language, you can typically access bytes and power-of-two multiples of these, sometimes with special alignment requirements (there's usually also bit operations, but while they only *change* one bit, they still work on whole bytes/words).

All of that is, however, not very interesting, and also widely irrelevant for you. It is first and foremost the compiler's (or interpreter's) job to make sure that when you speak of an integer or a character, that whatever you want comes out at the other end. It is also the tool's responsibility to convert one into another if possible, and produce an error if not possible.
You do not even know for certain whether the value of an integer or a character has a memory location at all (it may very well be stored in a register) unless you explicitly enforce that.

You cannot distinguish a byte at some memory location that came from a "character" from a byte that belongs to an "integer". They look just the same.

And while it is possible to read the raw bytes of one type as another type in most languages, this is not something you normally need to do (or should do).